# How to rename a folder and its contents at a time, according to the input, using cocoa?

Tags: objective-c

I have a folder as 'rootfolder', There are some other subfolders as (rat, cat, hat) inside the 'rootfolder'. I want to rename the matching character. For example if user want to replace 't' with 'z'.Then the 'rootfolder' renamed in 'roozfolder' similarly subfolders will be as (raz, caz, haz)..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function to deal with all the subfolders of subfolders. Here's some pseudocode:

```
function recursive_rename(current_directory)
    for each item in current_directory
        if item is a directory
            for each subitem in item
                recursive_rename(subitem)
            rename(item)
```

I'm assuming from your description that you only want to rename directories, right? Not normal items? If not, it would just be

```
function recursive_rename(current_directory)
    for each item in current_directory
        for each subitem in item
            recursive_rename(subitem)
        rename(item)
```

Comment: The `NSFileManager` class has all the methods you'll need to explore the file system. See Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-2894).